# Android - text dialog popup from an option menu

Tags: android, menu, dialog, popup, android-optionsmenu

A simple question. I want a static dialog message with ONLY text to popup when pressed a button in an options menu. This is my menu code:

```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.icon:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
                startActivity(intent);
           case R.id.help:
               //popup window code here
       }
       return true;
   }
}
```

How do I do it the easiest way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.icon:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
            startActivity(intent);
       case R.id.help:
           //popup window code here
Toast.makeText(this, "This is the Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
   return true;
}
}
```

or u can i use the dialog boxes

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.icon:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
            startActivity(intent);
       case R.id.help:
           //popup window code here
 AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // set the message to display
        alertbox.setMessage("This is the alertbox!");

        // add a neutral button to the alert box and assign a click listener
        alertbox.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            // click listener on the alert box
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // the button was clicked

            }
        });

        // show it
        alertbox.show();

   }
   return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Your second option seems to work, a dialog box pops up, but immediatly after that it turns back to Main.class activity. What's the problem? :)

Comment: Damn... Don't you have any clue? The code looks pretty simple. :/

Comment: He asked for a Popup not isn't there a popup class to?

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple dialog

```
static final int DIALOG_MESSAGE_ID= 0;

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  switch(id) {
  case DIALOG_MESSAGE_ID:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Your message ")//your message
       });
    return builder.create();
    break;
  }
  return null;
}


//in your code
case R.id.help:
  showDialog(DIALOG_MESSAGE_ID);
```

more at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
dialog.setMessage("Blah Blah...");
dialog.show();
```